# DJango FileSystem .url reading from wrong location

Tags: python, django, url, file-system-storage

I have a form containing an ImageField and a FileField

The files are uploading to the correct folders, however when I try to retrieve the url to display on screen it gives me an incorrect location

```
    fs_img = FileSystemStorage(location='media/images/')
    imageName = fs_img.save(image.name,image)
    uploaded_image_url = fs_img.url(imageName)
```

E.G. Images upload as **media/images/profile_image.jpg** 
However when I try to retrieve the url of the file that just saved, in order to save the location to a DB, it retrieves it as **media/profile_image.jpg** which doesn't exist

I am aware that the default location used by FileSystemStorage is **MEDIA_ROOT** and that seems to be just what **fs_img.url(imageName)** is using
where

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Also, I have found that in the models.py file using an upload_to setting has no effect

```
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to = 'media/images/',
    default='media/no_image.png'
)
```

How do I get fs_img.url(imageName) to return the correct URL so that I can save it to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i fixed this as follows:

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

FS_IMAGE_UPLOADS = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'images/')
FS_IMAGE_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_URL,'images/')

FS_DOCUMENT_UPLOADS = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'documents/')
FS_DOCUMENT_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_URL,'documents/')
```

**views.py**

```
image = request.FILES['image']
document = request.FILES['document']
fs_img = FileSystemStorage(
        location = settings.FS_IMAGE_UPLOADS,
        base_url= settings.FS_IMAGE_URL
    )
imageName = fs_img.save(image.name,image)
uploaded_image_url = fs_img.url(imageName)

fs_doc = FileSystemStorage(
        location = settings.FS_DOCUMENT_UPLOADS,
        base_url=settings.FS_DOCUMENT_URL
    )
documentName = fs_doc.save(document.name, document)
uploaded_document_url = fs_doc.url(documentName)
```

**uploaded_image_url** and **uploaded_document_url** values are now returning correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether image is saving that media folder. If it saving only problem with serving the image means you need to add this line of code in **Project Urls**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So whenever you are trying to serve the image django will automatically append the url and serve the static datas. For Further reference use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) . Let me know if this works